# Comparison of data to ground truth

Tags: correlation

Anyway, I have paired distributions of values, all between 0 and 1 and I want to compare them.  One is simulated data, and is thus the 'truth' and I would like to compare how closely the other sets of data match this and also quantify which is the most similar. So, for example:

```
truth<-c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.45,0.5,0.55,0.6)

set1<-c(0.1,0.21,0.36,0.5,0.45,0.57,0.55,0.62)

set2<-c(0.08,0.2,0.36,0.57,0.45,0.54,0.56,0.62)
```

I thought about a simple correlation test and $R^2$ value to compare different pairs, but ultimately this would be testing how closely data points are grouped around an inferred regression line, which I don't think is what I want.  Because I know one of them is the 'truth' I really want to test how well the data points group around $x=y$.  Is there an obvious test for comparing whether set1 vs truth is a better match than set2 vs truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define any metric you like to decide whether a candidate is better than another. The most popular is the sum of squared errors (I'm going to call the truth $T$ and the candidates $X$ and $Y$):

$$SSE_X = \sum_{i=1}^{n_X} \left( X_i - T_i \right)^2$$
$$SSE_Y = \sum_{i=1}^{n_Y} \left( Y_i - T_i \right)^2$$

Whichever SSE is smaller is the one that is "closest", in the sense of Euclidean distance, to the truth. 
EDIT: I'm using MATLAB but I get answers $SSE_{X}=0.019$ and $SSE_Y=0.035$, so the first set is "better" according to your defined rule of betterness. Now, the Mean Squared Error is also a possible rule; the Mean Absolute Deviation, the Mean Percentage Error: there's a whole host of metrics you can use.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply.  So what test would I use to see whether the first model is statistically a better fit than the second one?

Comment: @Alan it depends what type of data you have and what you believe the generating distribution to be. Can you assume that your data are Gaussian (normal)?

Comment: yes, I believe I can assume that they are normal and independent.

Comment: @Alan, the most straightforward method would be to compare the [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error#Predictor) values for each candidate. The set with the lower MSE is the desired approximation of "truth". Mathematically,
$$MSE_X = \frac{1}{n_X}\sum_{i=1}^{n_X} (X_i -T_i)^2 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ MSE_Y = \frac{1}{n_Y}\sum_{i=1}^{n_Y} (Y_i -T_i)^2$$